# Spresense-Arduino のスケッチ例 pcm_capture が終了してしまう．音声波形データを外部に取り出したい

Tags: arduino, spresense

Spresense Arduino Library (バージョン1.1.2) のスケッチ例`Audio/application/pcm_capture.ino`，また`Audio/application/pcm_capture_objif.ino`を試用しています．

本プログラムを実行しシリアルモニタを開くと，`pcm_capture`, `pcm_capture_objif`ともに， `"Recording Start!"` の後数秒間は `void signal_process(uint32_t size)` 内の `printf` が実行されているのが見えますが， `WARNING: Insufficient buffer area.` と出て終了してしまいます．

1. バッファのデータ構造について

   void signal_process(uint32_t size)

内の

```
printf("Size %d [%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x %02x ...]\n",
         size,
         s_buffer[0],
         s_buffer[1],
         s_buffer[2],
         s_buffer[3],
         s_buffer[4],
         s_buffer[5],
         s_buffer[6],
         s_buffer[7]);
```

において，例えばMIC_Aの音の波形データが欲しければ，どのように読み取ればよいのでしょうか？

```
buffer_size = 6144; /*768sample,4ch,16bit*/
```

とあるので，`s_buffer[0]~[7]`のうち2bytesが`MIC_A`の1sampleを表していることは予想できますが，（FIFOオーバーフローのためか）サンプルプログラムが途中で終了してしまうため検証が難しいです．

2. 複数のマイクの音を収集し，リアルタイムにWi-FiでPCに送信するか，SPI通信で他のマイコンに送信したりしたいのですが，

   void signal_process(uint32_t size)

内に処理を追加しても，同様に途中でプログラムが終了してしまうことが考えられます．ストリーミングで外部に波形データを取り出すための適切な方法はありますでしょうか．

3. また "object if" の "if" はインターフェースの意味なのでしょうか．

よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: 実証したわけではないので、コメントで…

    WARNING: Insufficient buffer area.

と出ていますので、おそらくprintf 出力で時間がかかってしまい録音処理が追い付かずバッファが溢れてしまっているのだと思います。

十分なサイズの処理用データバッファ（例えばリングバッファ）を用意して、void signal_process(uint32_t size) 内で順次コピーし、別スレッドで処理用データバッファ内のデータを読み込み、外部インターフェースに送信するようにすればうまくいくのではないでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます．ご指摘を元にいろいろと試した結果，確かにsignal_process内に時間のかかる処理を含めると同様のエラーが発生しました．16bit16kHz4chで音声信号を取得し，SPI通信8MHzで別のマイコンに送信する処理を含めてみたところ，Little Endianで希望通りのデータを得ることができました．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

void signal_process(uint32_t size)
等を例にすると、
そのまま動かすコードではないと思います。

一例ですが、48kHzサンプリングのデータを、
printfするのは、馴染まない気がしますので、
例えば、1024回に1回だけ表示されるとかがいいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます．確かにprintfでは厳しく，ご指摘を元にいろいろと試した結果，16bit16kHz4chで音声信号を取得し，SPI通信8MHzで別のマイコンに送信する処理を含めてみたところ，Little Endianで希望通りのデータを得ることができました．